# MongoDB Linq driver casting exception

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB and search a collection using linq. I used Nuget to install all of the mongo tools, and am getting a error saying that GetCollection returns IMongoCollection but AsQueryable requires a MongoCollection. I know I can cast here to solve the problem, I think I am probably doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Bson;

namespace Services.Data.Repositories.Concrete
{


    public class AccountRepository : IRepository<Account>
    {
        private IMongoDatabase _database;
        private IMongoClient _client;

        public AccountRepository()
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString;
            _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
           _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");

        }
        public async Task<Account> GetAsync(string id)
        {
            var accounts = _database.GetCollection<Account>("accounts");
            var account = await accounts.Find(f => f.Id == id).FirstAsync();
            return account;
        }

        public async Task<List<Account>> GetAllAsync(bool onlyActive)
        {
            var accounts = _database.GetCollection<Account>("accounts");
            return accounts.AsQueryable<Account>().ToList();
        }
```

If you look at the GetAllAsync method, this is where I am getting a compile error. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Exception: 
Error   5   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection' to 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection'

**Update**
I checked and there isn't a FindAll method on the IMongoCollection interface. I was able to temporarily solve my problem with the code below, but it certainly doesn't seem like the best approach. Is there something I am missing or is this standard implementation?

```
    public async Task<List<Account>> GetAllAsync(bool onlyActive)
    {
        var accounts = _database.GetCollection<Account>("accounts") as MongoCollection;
        return accounts.AsQueryable<Account>().ToList();
    }
```

Comment: So it turns out my problem was that I was using the 2.0 beta nuget package. Apparently, they need to fix the documentation/AsQueryable method before this version will work.

Comment: Did you get this working with the 2.0 driver? I want to use a collection as queryable.

Comment: I ended up using the release version of the driver and it worked fine. I am not sure if 2.0 is a release candidate yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can see AsQueryable's definition:

```
public static IQueryable<T> AsQueryable<T>(this MongoCollection<T> collection);
public static IQueryable<T> AsQueryable<T>(this MongoCollection collection);.
```

parameter was MongoCollection ...

you can change

```
return accounts.AsQueryable<Account>().ToList();
```

to

```
return accounts.FindAll();
```